# Does a singleton instance make sense in this case?

Tags: php, oop, singleton

I know this is a very debated topic among programmers and I already read a lot about the cons and pros about the singleton pattern.

Still I want to ask about the singleton pattern.

I'm creating a small PHP framework and I'm stuck the way I'm handling Cookies in my framework.

**Upfront:**

The framework provides factory functions for every module so from the outside it is not clear whether the instance is a singleton or not.

Example:

```
$db     = Framework::DB(); // always a new instance
$cookie = Framework::Cookie(); // singleton (maybe?)
```

**My take:**

Provide a singleton cookie instance which can be used to mutate cookies (set, delete, get):

```
class Cookie {
     public function set($name, $value) {

     }
}
```

My reasoning is that cookies are a global state and you cannot create a fresh cookie environment - it is always provided by the browser. 
For me it makes just no sense to instantiate a new cookie class instance.

But maybe I'm missing something.

**Essentially I wonder if there is better solution (without using the singleton pattern) or if that is one of the cases where a singleton actually makes sense.**

Comment: The reason against singletons is that you shouldn't be instantiating stuff all over the place to begin with. The correct answer to the question "singleton factory?" is: *dependency injection.* Then it's simply a matter of whether or not you create more than one instance which you then inject everywhere.

Comment: Yes, I planned to use dependency injection. The question for me is just if the top level object should be a singleton or not.

Comment: So for example a class that uses cookies `class User { public function __construct(Framework\Cookie $cookie) {} }` and then `new User(Framework::Cookie());`

Comment: Then if you're using a dependency injection container or something of that sort, you typically only instantiate each dependency once anyway and inject it everywhere it's needed. `Cookie` doesn't need to be "a singleton", but practically speaking you'll be instantiating it just once anyway.

Comment: Oops.. I think I mixed up singleton pattern and the act of only creating one instance. Is my understanding after reading your comments correct that this question isn't really about the singleton pattern but much rather about "should I create only one instance of this class"?

Comment: Ergo: as long as you can instantiate multiple instances of a class it's not using the singleton pattern.

Comment: Indeed. "Singleton" specifically means that you *cannot* instantiate it more than once.

Comment: Thank you so much! This resolved my problem completely! If you want you can write a short answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Singleton basically means you can only create 1 instance of a class, I personally don't see the point in hard-coding that into a class because generally speaking a class is something created so you can create multiple objects.

For your database example, for most websites only handling 1 database it should be fine. But what if in the future you want to connect to an external database using the same API? Ohh, you cannot because I implemented a singleton interface.

Now lets talk about your cookie example, each website has the ability to store multiple cookies. Why create a singleton out of that? Design that class so that `$cookie2 = new Cookie('name')` references to the other cookie. Yes, it can all be done with 1 class, a singleton where each time you need to parse a name to determine what cookie to put it in.

There are very few cases a singleton design pattern can be useful, at least in PHP. Most people use a container to store a variable that references to a single instance of a class (basically a singleton). However that container can be changed for another container, perhaps to something like a test environment referring to a different database and a different cookie all while using the same API.